# Drag and Drop to folder behavior

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, widget

I have been searching around and learning about android widget programming. I am wondering about interaction in android widget. Is it possible for me to create a home screen widget that allow users to drag and drop other application icons to my widget? (behave like folder) If so, could you provide me some useful resources or examples of how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Edited: I have found a widget called Semi Folder is similar to what I am looking for but this widget still not allow users to drag and drop to itself. It allows users to select and store applications via activity. Therefore, I still look for the solution of drag and drop to my widget.

Comment: Several homescreens replacements have this behavior as well as the Folder item that you can add to your homescreen.  As for source files the actual android source is a great place to start.